# Executar função somente quando o user soltar o input type="range"?

Tags: jquery, vídeo

Estou usando um `input[type="range"]` como barra de progresso para um player de vídeo, é ao simular o evento para mudar o tempo do vídeo pois só quero que a ação seja executada somente depois que o usuário soltar o `input`, Exemplo:

```
$('input range').bind('change click mousemove', function() {
    var atual_val = $(this).val();
    vid.currenTime = atual_val;
});
```

Se eu apenas deixar dessa forma, cada vez que o usuário deslizar / arrastar o `input`, enquanto a ação é executa o player vai "bugar", logo eu quero que o vídeo só mude o `currentTime` após o usuário soltar a input, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é usar o `.on mouse event`, como por exemplo:

```
.on('mouseup', handler) ou .on('mousedown', handler)
```

O JQuery permite o uso de atalhos para chamar estes eventos, como:

```
$( "#alvo" ).mouseup(function() {
  alert( "Atalho para .mouseup() foi chamado!" );
});
```

Sendo assi, seu exemplo ficaria desta forma

```
$('input range').mouseup(function() {
    var atual_val = $(this).val();
    vid.currenTime = atual_val;
});
```

Para maiores referências, consulte:
https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente bem xD